# adb command for getting ip address assigned by operator

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I need to fetch the IPaddress assigned by the operator after a successful 3G or LTE data call.

```
$adb shell netcfg >> doesnt have the assigned IP address.
```

I tried `adb shell dumpsys` and grep ip address, but in vain. Any help/pointers?

Comment: related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/how-can-i-see-what-ip-address-my-android-phone-has

Answer (score 74):

Try this command, it will help you to get ipaddress

```
adb shell ifconfig tiwlan0
```

tiwlan0 is the name of the wi-fi network interface on the device. This is generic command for getting ipaddress,

```
 adb shell netcfg
```

It will output like this

```
usb0     DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0×00001002
sit0     DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0×00000080
ip6tnl0  DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0×00000080
gannet0  DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0×00001082
rmnet0   UP    112.79.87.220   255.0.0.0       0x000000c1
rmnet1   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0×00000080
rmnet2   DOWN  0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0×00000080
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.Still im not able to get the IP address assigned by the network. When I tried the commands, the output is as provided below:

Comment: Great answer. It's 'wlan0' for the regular wi-fi connection: `adb shell ifconfig wlan0`

Comment: 1. `ifconfig` not available (Cyanogen 13, Nexus 5).  2. netcfg needs root. 
use `ip` command, it's part of 'iproute2'.

Comment: Just `adb shell ifconfig` now shows all interfaces on Android 8 by default.

Comment: Needs root: Try ```adb shell ip -o a```

Comment: `adb shell ifconfig wlan0` with [LineageOS](https://lineageos.org/)

Answer (score 27):

**Try:**

```
adb shell ip addr show rmnet0
```

**It  will return something like that:**

```
3: rmnet0: <UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/[530]
    inet 172.22.1.100/29 scope global rmnet0
    inet6 fc01:abab:cdcd:efe0:8099:af3f:2af2:8bc/64 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8099:af3f:2af2:8bc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**This part is your IPV4 assigned by the operator**

> inet 172.22.1.100

**This part is your IPV6 assigned by the operator**

> inet6 fc01:abab:cdcd:efe0:8099:af3f:2af2:8bc

Comment: I think that everybody should start using `ip addr show <INTERFACE>` because the `ifconfig` way is deprecated on recent linux systems and I noticed that `ifconfig` behaviour on a Lollipop Nexus 5 and Marshmallow Nexus 5X was different for `ifconfig` and `netcfg`, so `ip addr show` way was the only way I could get both working predictably.

Comment: should be accepted.
1. ifconfig not available (Cyanogen 13, Nexus 5). 2. netcfg needs root. use ip command, it's part of 'iproute2'

Comment: This works. ipconfig isn't available (s6 edge, stock OS) and netcfg cannot be recognized. It is probably root only as vigilancer said.

Comment: Just `adb shell ip address show` shows all interfaces by default on Android 8.

Answer (score 19):

Try this command for Version <= Marshmallow,

```
adb devices
```

> List of devices attached 
>   38ccdc87 device

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

> restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

```
adb shell ip addr show wlan0
```

24: wlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:c1:ee:6b:22:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet **192.168.0.18**/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd01::1d45:6b7a:a3b:5f4d/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 287sec preferred_lft 287sec
    inet6 fd01::aec1:eeff:fe6b:22f1/64 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft 287sec preferred_lft 287sec
    inet6 fe80::aec1:eeff:fe6b:22f1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

To connect to your device run this

```
adb connect 192.168.0.18
```

connected to 192.168.0.18:5555

Make sure you have adb inside this location **android-sdk\platform-tools**

Comment: If `adb tcpip [port not 5555]` connecting to the Ip alone will not work. A port has to be supplied if it isn't 5555

Comment: No need to connect adb via wifi, can also use in USB mode.
Also, you don't want show wlan0 but simply ```adb shell ip -o a```

Answer (score 17):

According to comments: netcfg was removed in Android 6

Try

```
adb shell netcfg
```

Or

```
adb shell <device here or leave out if one device>
shell@android:/ $netcfg
```

Comment: With this I get `error: device not found` . `su` followed by `netcfg` worked for me

Answer (score 12):

You can get the device ip address by this way:

```
adb shell ip route > addrs.txt
#Case 1:Nexus 7
#192.168.88.0/23 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.89.48

#Case 2: Smartsian T1,Huawei C8813
#default via 192.168.88.1 dev eth0  metric 30
#8.8.8.8 via 192.168.88.1 dev eth0  metric 30
#114.114.114.114 via 192.168.88.1 dev eth0  metric 30
#192.168.88.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.89.152 metric 30
#192.168.88.1 dev eth0  scope link  metric 30

ip_addrs=$(awk {'if( NF >=9){print $9;}'} addrs.txt)

echo "the device ip address is $ip_addrs"
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try this command:

```sh
adb shell ip addr show rmnet0  | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cut -d / -f 1
```

**It  will return your IPV4 assigned by the operator**

> 172.22.1.215

### Note:

`rmnet0` should be replaced with your interface my case was `rmnet0` usually is `eth0`.

If u want to get the list of interfaces use this command:

```sh
ip link show
```

You will get something like this:

```sh
1: lo:  mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ac:6f:65:31:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::baac:6fff:fe65:31e5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:6a:ca:9b:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: pan0:  mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/ether 92:0a:e7:31:e0:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vmnet1:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.121.1/24 brd 192.168.121.255 scope global vmnet1
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vmnet8:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.179.1/24 brd 192.168.179.255 scope global vmnet8
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Where usually,

- `lo` – Loopback interface.
- `eth0` – Your first Ethernet network interface on Linux.
- `wlan0` – Wireless network interface in Linux.

Answer (score 4):

You also can try this:

**Step 1:** adb shell
**Step 2:** ip -f inet addr show wlan0

Answer (score 3):

adb shell ip addr > ippdetails.txt
This will get all list of ip's assigned to devices.

Answer (score 3):

To get all IPs (**WIFI and data SIM**) even on a **non-rooted** phone in 2019 use:

`adb shell ip -o a`

The output looks like:

```
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
1: lo    inet6 ::1/128 scope host \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: dummy0    inet6 fe80::489c:2ff:fe4a:00005/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: rmnet_data1    inet6 fe80::735d:50fb:2e2:0000/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
21: r_rmnet_data0    inet6 fe80::e38:ce2a:523a:0000/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: wlan0    inet 192.168.178.0/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global wlan0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: wlan0    inet6 fe80::c2ee:fbff:fe4a:0000/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

You can connect either through adb shell or run the command `ip -o a` directly in a terminal emulator. Again, no root required.

Answer (score 2):

download this app from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) it will help you to rum all commands. I have run netcfg and it gives the result as attached in screen.

[image: output screen]

Comment: 1) netcfg is root only. 2) That app is just access to the adb shell. Doing `adb shell` is much easier than downloading the app

Answer (score 2):

For IP address- `adb shell ifconfig`
under `wlan0     Link encap:UNSPEC`
you will have your ip address written

Answer (score 1):

```
ip route | grep rmnet_data0 | cut -d" " -f1 | cut -d"/" -f1
```

Change `rmnet_data0` to the desired nic, in my case, `rmnet_data0` represents the data nic.

To get a list of the available nic's you can use `ip route`

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect device via USB and make sure debugging is working, then run:

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect `adb shell ip addr show wlan0  | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cut -d / -f 1`:5555
```

2. Disconnect USB and proceed with wireless debugging.
3. When you're done and want to switch back to USB debugging, run:

```
adb -s`adb shell ip addr show wlan0  | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cut -d / -f 1`:5555
```

*note*:

- wlan0 – Wireless network interface in Linux.