# ADB WIFI Connect - how to?

Tags: android, adbwireless

I want to run an app on my device to do that I am using ADB `Wifi Connect` plugin. Both my phone and laptop are connected to same wifi network. I am still not able to run the app on my phone. Please give an appropriate solution.

Error while connecting my Android device using `ADB WIFI Connect plugin`.

[image]

Comment: what error you are getting? Post it here.

Comment: Well, i have attached the Screenshot above. The error is [INFO]  For launching outside of the IDE, find the runnable jar file here: 
"C:\Users\Maddy\.AndroidStudio3.0\config\plugins\ADBWiFiConnect\lib\ADBWiFiConnectGUI.jar"

Comment: At least first time you have connected through physical cable then after you will able to run using wifi adb. Hope this tips will help you

Comment: You can directly use adb commands and see whether it works.

Comment: Check whether this helps : https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless

Comment: try this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169249/adb-command-for-getting-ip-address-assigned-by-operator/44647297#44647297

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio then follow the below procedures:

Connect your smart phone with your system via physical cable.
make sure your smartphone and computer is connected via same network.

1.Open terminal in your android studio.
2. type "adb devices", which will show you the list of devices attached.
3. type "adb tcpip 5555".
4. type "adb your phone ip address:5555".

Hope this will help you